# Checkstyle Can't Generate Report With Custom Check

Tags: checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I am trying to create my own custom check for Checkstyle. I created an artifact and gave it on the classpath (dependency in the `POM`). Then included it in my `configuration.xml` file. I am getting the following error:

```
 An error has occurred in Checkstyle report generation.: Failed during checkstyle configuration: cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate 'com.lft.cos.checkstyle.custom.MethodsOrderCheck' class.
```

Can someone point me to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Blundell could you please help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Checkstyle isn't finding your class by that classpath. Either you don't have the class as a dependency with checkstyle or you have a typo somewhere.

Comment: I was making a silly mistake. I had added it to the application classpath, instead of Checkstyle's classpath smh. The problem is resolved now. Thanks.